# Automate SSH Connection from Windows?

Tags: c#, automation, ssh

I'm trying to automate an SSH connection to a server from a windows box. I would like to ssh to the server, log in (using password not certificate), execute a few commands, read their output, then close the connection.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Are there any C# libraries, or command line SSH clients that could be called from C#? It doesn't have to be C#, whatever works will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it free, [SharpSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpssh) is the most known (although not the most frequently updated). There was a recent rewrite of SSH client in C#, somehere on sourceforge, but I don't remember it's name and can't find it at the moment. *Update:* it's [DotnetSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetssh/).

There also exist several commercial solutions, which include vendor-provided support and timely updates. Our [SSHBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssh.php) package is one of the options.

Comment: I'll try and convince the higher ups to give you guys some money, but this is a small project. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I also found these for anyone who comes here by google: http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensshwindows/ http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetssh/

Comment: @Petey Mind the GPL license of `opensshwindows` . DotnetSSH is the one I was thinking about (I'll update the answer with the link now).

Answer (score 4):

If you want something free, reliable, open-source. [get PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) - Plink is especially friendly for programs.

Comment: so what? the code is actively worked upon; this guy is a developer, not some end user noob, I'm sure he knows how to checkout from SVN.

Comment: would you like to live in the house which is actively worked upon?

Comment: I guess you're not interested in what I'm saying; I already pointed out that it is actively worked upon, just that they don't release pre-compiled binaries frequently.

Comment: indeed I am interested in OP getting the objective picture, and the picture is that the product is updated once in 4 years.

Comment: As of today, Sharp SSH 1.1.1.13, last update on 2013-05-28, Putty 0.64 last update on 2015-02-28. Take your choices.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries to do this - for example http://www.rebex.net/ssh-pack/default.aspx (not affiliated, just happy customer) or http://www.eldos.com/sbb/ (not affiliated, just happy customer)